# Compiling for Apple Macintosh with Visual Studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to compile with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows a Apple Macintosh compatible application?

If so, how do we do it? Are there only certain projects?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @JörgWMittag How? Is it only certain types of projects?